# Array group and reduce - Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, filter, reduce

I want to group and reduce the following array:

```
    [
      {
        "code": "202008001",
        "estado": "borrador",
        "cliente": "ENTEL",
        "tipo": "Administracion"
      },
      {
        "code": "202008002",
        "estado": "borrador",
        "cliente": "ENTEL",
        "tipo": "Administracion"
      },
      {
        "code": "202008002",
        "estado": "borrador",
        "cliente": "ENTEL",
        "tipo": "Monitoreo Seguridad"
      },
    ]
```

first i need to group by the **code** property and then merge or reduce by **tipo**. This is the result I want:

```
    [
      {
        "code": "202008001",
        "estado": "borrador",
        "cliente": "ENTEL",
        "tipos": ["Administracion"]
      },
      {
        "code": "202008002",
        "estado": "borrador",
        "cliente": "ENTEL",
        "tipos": ["Administracion","Monitoreo Seguridad"]
      }
    ]
```

I tested multiple forms to do this only using **reduce** but without any sucess. thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In reduce, just check if an item with the same code exists, if so, push to the existing .tipos, if not, add a new item, but rename tipo to tipos and make it an array.

```js
const r = [
  {
    "code": "202008001",
    "estado": "borrador",
    "cliente": "ENTEL",
    "tipo": "Administracion"
  },
  {
    "code": "202008002",
    "estado": "borrador",
    "cliente": "ENTEL",
    "tipo": "Administracion"
  },
  {
    "code": "202008002",
    "estado": "borrador",
    "cliente": "ENTEL",
    "tipo": "Monitoreo Seguridad"
  },
].reduce((carry, current) => {
    const existing = carry.find((el) => el.code === current.code);
    if (existing) existing.tipos.push(current.tipo);
    else {
        const {tipo, ...el} = current;
        carry.push({...el, tipos: [tipo]});
    }
    return carry;
}, []);

console.log(r);
```

Comment: Amazing! I spent hours tried to figure it, Thanks you very much!!

Answer (score 0):

With reduce build an object consisting of the properties from the code, from which at the end the values are taken tio get the wished result as an array.
For each object I look in the result-object if this contains a property with the value from the code. If not so so add this property an store as value the new element. After this replace the property tipo through an array with the tipo inside. Otherways just add to the tipo array the new tipo.

```js
let arr =   [
      {
        "code": "202008001",
        "estado": "borrador",
        "cliente": "ENTEL",
        "tipo": "Administracion"
      },
      {
        "code": "202008002",
        "estado": "borrador",
        "cliente": "ENTEL",
        "tipo": "Administracion"
      },
      {
        "code": "202008002",
        "estado": "borrador",
        "cliente": "ENTEL",
        "tipo": "Monitoreo Seguridad"
      },
    ];
    
let result = Object.values(arr.reduce((acc, cur) => {
    if (!acc.hasOwnProperty(cur)) {
        acc[cur.code] = cur;
        acc[cur.code].tipo = [cur.tipo];
    } else {
        acc.tipo.push(cur.tipo);
    }
    return acc;
}, {}));

console.log(result);
```